# Difference between "tout simplement", "seulement" and "tout"

Tags: sens, adverbes

What's the difference between these sentences?

> "J'aimerais tout simplement bien vivre"
>
> "J'aimerais seulement bien vivre"
>
> "J'aimerais tout bien vivre"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> J'aimerais tout simplement bien vivre.
>
> ---> I would like to live well, and it's something natural.
>
> J'aimerais seulement bien vivre.
>
> ---> I would like to live well, and it's not very demanding.
>
> J'aimerais tout bien vivre
>
> ---> I would like to live well everything.

Answer (score 3):

Dans tes exemples *tout simplement* et *simplement* ont des sens assez proches :

> J'aimerais tout simplement bien vivre

−>  *I'd just like to live a good life*.

> J'aimerais seulement bien vivre

−>  j'aimerais bien vivre et c'est tout. *The only thing I'd like is to live well/to live a good life.*

> J'aimerais tout bien vivre

peut être compris d'au moins deux façons différentes :

- *I'd like everything in my life to be enjoyable.*
- *I'd like to take everything in my life easy.*